# Making features in Solr using "Microsoft Learning to Rank Datasets"

Tags: solr

I'm very new to Solr and I want to score some features. I've a sample `feature.json` as follows:

```
[ 
   {
    "store": "myfeature_store",
    "name" : "originalScore",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.OriginalScoreFeature",
    "params" : {}
   },
   {
    "store": "myfeature_store",
    "name" : "titleLength",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.FieldLengthFeature",
    "params" : {
    "field":"title" 
     }
   },
   {
    "store": "myfeature_store",
    "name" : "contentLength",
    "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.FieldLengthFeature",
    "params" : {
    "field":"content" 
     }
   }, 
   {
   "store": "myfeature_store",
   "name": "titleScore",
   "class": "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
   "params": {
       "q":"{!dismax qf=title} ${query}"
   }
   },
   {
   "store": "myfeature_store",
   "name": "contentScore",
   "class": "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
   "params": {
       "q":"{!dismax qf=content} ${query}"
   }
   }, 
   {
   "store": "myfeature_store",
   "name": "freshness",
   "class": "org.apache.solr.ltr.feature.SolrFeature",
   "params" : {
           "q" : "{!func}recip( ms(NOW, lastModified), 3.16e-11, 1, 1)"
   }
   }
]
```

I want to train SVM on "Microsoft Learning to Rank Datasets" ([link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/mslr/)). It contains 136 features. How to make a `feature.json` using features given in the dataset ? I'm unable to find any useful tutorial on this.